# Сбор статистической информации (DDD vs Transaction Script)

Tags: model, ddd, transaction, cqrs

Есть список серверов. На каждом сервере свой список игроков. Периодически список игроков, как и данные сервера изменяются. По каждому игроку ведется отдельная статистика.

Для сбора информации о сервере и игроках создал отдельный контекст. Решил применить CQRS.

Для вывода статистической информации создал отдельную Read Model. Здесь все довольно просто - обычные операции чтения.

Возник **вопрос** относительно области записи информации.

Что лучше применить при получении обработке статистических данных:

1. Формировать полноценную **доменную модель** с набором агрегатов, событий и других тактических шаблонов
2. Использовать обычные **сценарии транзакции** (Transaction Script)

Я склоняюсь к использованию *сценария транзакции*:

- Простота реализации
- Разовое обновление большого количества данных

Использование в данном случае *DDD* меня смущает:

- Не представляю использование подхода DDD при обработке статистической
  информации - потенциально большое количество абстракций
- Репозиторий предполагает редактирование одного агрегата за раз.
  Допустим у меня игрок сервера является отдельным агрегатом с
  соответствующей статистической информацией. При необходимости
  обновления информации о большом количестве игроков будет большая
  нагрузка на базу данных.

*С другой стороны*:

- DDD позволит нормально инкапсулировать логику валидации данных.
- Transaction Script со временем трудно поддерживать.

Очень нужен Ваш совет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подход DDD хорош, когда у вас богатая предметная область: движение документов, регламенты, взаимодействие разных сущностей в рамках одного бизнес-сценария. Задачи обработки данных, тем более быстрой обработки данных, плохо ложатся на DDD, поскольку логика в них относительно простая, и для их решения достаточно SQL.

То есть, DDD слишком сложен для решения таких простых задач. Кроме того, DDD может оказаться не слишком производительным подходом, поскольку, например, предполагает загрузку агрегата целиком.

Это с одной стороны. С другой стороны, подход DDD это не набор жёстких правил, а набор принципов. Мы можем выделить под обработку данных *ограниченный контекст* (bounded context), где модели будут проще, чем в основном контексте.

Правила, что *хранилище* (repository) может обрабатывать только один агрегат за раз, в действительности не существует. *Репозиторий* — коллекция сверх-большого размера, и поэтому мы не можем работать со всеми её элементами непосредственно, только какими-то кусками небольшого размера. Так определяет репозитории Эванс.

Репозиторий *может* содержать методы групповой вставки, удаления и изменения данных, если это продиктовано предметной областью. Скорее, надо обратить внимание на то, чтобы каждый такой вызов выполнялся быстро, то есть нельзя создавать метод *обновления всех записей в базе*, которых может быть несколько миллионов. Вместо него нужен метод порционного (постраничного) обновления, при этом размер каждой порции может составлять 100 или 1000 записей.

Сущности для решения статистических задач не обладают поведением, поэтому в нашем ограниченном контексте мы используем паттерн *анемичная модель* (anemic domain model). Про него надо помнить, что его часто причисляют к анти-паттерном, и это вполне справедливо. Но в данном конкретном случае это правильное решение, поскольку, по сути, мы должны сделать срез данных в базе, и с помощью нескольких операций реляционной алгебры свести их к нескольким таблицам.

Второй подход я бы определил не просто как Transaction Script. В конечном итоге мы можем для подготовки отчётов использовать специализированное средство, которое будет иметь доступ к базе данных на чтение, какой-нибудь Microsoft Reporting Services. Возможно, нам придётся агрегировать промежуточные данные в соседней базе для того, чтобы позднее делать отчёты быстрее, и это мы сделаем на SQL.

В общем, мы не обязаны всё решение делать в рамках не только DDD, но и ООП. И даже не обязаны делать его на основном языке проекта Java/C#/Python. Здесь, скорее, определяющую роль играют навыки команды.

Единственное ограничение, которое я бы добавил к такой системе: статистическое приложение не должно менять данные в основной базе. Оно имеет доступ только для чтения, а если ему нужны собственные промежуточные данные, оно хранит их в отдельной схеме или отдельной базе. Это ограничение избавит вас от тонких ошибок.

Итого:

1. Если у вас вся команда пишет в основном на Java/C#/*подставьте свой язык*, то попробуйте ограниченный контекст с анемичными моделями и мощными репозиториями.
2. Если кто-то шарит в SQL/Reporting Services и так далее, можете сделать отдельное решение. Может оказаться быстрее и удобнее, чем делать то же самое на Java/C#.
3. Промежуточное решение: можно сделать выделенное решение на Java/C#, но с минимумом ООП. Можно использовать простые паттерны доступа к данным: row gateway, table gateway, transaction script и так далее.
4. Какой бы из вариантов вы ни выбрали, не пишите из второго решения в основную базу во избежание ошибок, которые трудно найти и исправить. Доступ к основной базе только для чтения, менять её может только основной контекст.